# How can I change what happens when I click on data in the RStudio Environment pane?

Tags: r, rstudio

The default behavior when clicking on data in the `Global Environment` pane in RStudio is to call `View()` on the data that was clicked.  Is it possible to replace `View()` with another function instead?

For instance, if I click on `df`, perhaps I would want it to run the code `head(df)` instead of `View(df)`.

I have changed my `.Rprofile` to automatically load the `DT` package, and my goal is that when I click on `df` for it to run `datatable(df)` instead of `View(df)` so that my data will appear in the viewer pane instead of the source pane and I can see both my code and the data at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell RStudio which function to call when a dataframe is clicked. You can, however, simply write your own `View()`. Try this:

```
View <- function(df) { datatable(df) }
```

Also note that the data viewer in RStudio can be popped out to a separate window (there's a small popout icon in the toolbar beneath the tab) for side-by-side viewing with code.

[image: popout]

Comment: This is great!  I wish I would have thought of it.